# Order Executes Stop Loss and Reversal On Same Bar

Tags: pine-script

My strategy is executing my stop loss and reversal order on the same bar.
This causes my position size to be outside my risk parameters.

I've seen some questions about this topic but I cant find an answer.
Can orders be executed on the same bar?

```
if (strategy.position_size < 1) and enterLong 
    strategy.entry(id="EL", long=true, qty=posSize,
        stop=upperband + syminfo.mintick)

if (strategy.position_size > -1) and enterShort 
    strategy.entry(id="ES", long=false, qty=posSize,
        stop=lowerband - syminfo.mintick)

if(strategy.position_size > 0) and preventShort
    strategy.exit(id="XL", stop=longStopPrice)
if(strategy.position_size < 0) and preventLong
    strategy.exit(id="XS", stop=shortStopPrice)
```

I want to be able to back test my strategy with accurate risk parameters.
My results are being skewed because the position sizes are too big.

Comment: Hmm interesting, perhaps add some delay?

Answer (score 0):

That behavior is due to a bug in the broker emulator. Should be fixed in the near future.

Note that it is poor practice to ask the same question in multiple places, as you risk getting different people researching and/or answering in parallel, as happened with this question.